# Characters showing up in string, how to remove them with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two string that look the same but aren't.

```
$ more /tmp/1
'[FORM-15801]

$ more /tmp/2
'[FORM‑15801]
```

I see the characters here.

```
$ sed -n l /tmp/1
'[FORM-15801]$


$ sed -n l /tmp/2
'[FORM\342\200\22115801]$
```

In python, how can i convert the contents of /tmp/2 to look like /tmp/2?

Comment: They do not look the same. The top one contains an en-dash – (U+2013), encoded as UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`unidecode`](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) module.

From the PyPI page:

> What Unidecode provides is a middle road: the function `unidecode()` takes Unicode data and tries to represent it in ASCII characters (i.e., the universally displayable characters between 0x00 and 0x7F), where the compromises taken when mapping between two character sets are chosen to be near what a human with a US keyboard would choose.